# Sending post request to https

Tags: java, post, https

I need to send a post request to a https address. I have a function that sends post messages currectly but i cant seem to make it work for https.

```
public static String serverCall(String link, String data){
     HttpURLConnection connection;
     OutputStreamWriter request = null;

         URL url = null;
         String response = null;
         String parameters = data;

         try
         {
             url = new URL(link);
             connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             connection.setDoOutput(true);
             connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
             connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 

             request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
             request.write(parameters);
             request.flush();
             request.close();
             String line = "";
             InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
             {
                 sb.append(line + "\n");
             }
             // Response from server after  process will be stored in response variable.
             response = sb.toString();

             isr.close();
             reader.close();

         }
         catch(IOException e)
         {
             // Error
         }

         return response;
```

}

i have tryed using HttpsURLConnection insted of HttpURLConnection, i am still getting null from my server.

Comment: Does your server support SSL?

Comment: Don't show the code that is working. Show the code that is *not* working. How did you try *using HttpsURLConnection*? Where are you *getting null from your server*? Give examples of the arguments you pass into methods and constructors.

Comment: the code doesnt work for https... i tryed replacing HttpURLConnection    to HttpsURLConnection

Answer (score 0):

you should call `connect();`

```
....
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.connect();
....
```

Comment: works with or without on http, doesnt help my problem with the https connection...